# Finding a value given Taylor Polynomial

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, derivatives, taylor-expansion

So I was given the following prompt:

"A function has derivatives of all orders at $x = 0$. Let $P_n(x)$ denote the nth degree Taylor polynomial about $x = 0$. It is known that $f(0)=6$, $P_1(-\frac{1}{2})=-4$, and $P_2(-\frac{1}{2})=-6$. Find $f''(0)$."

I guess I'm a bit confused about where I'd start here. I understand that I was given the $c$ value and the coefficients of the first couple of terms here, but I'm a bit confused about how I would apply this information in this specific context. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: try writing the definition of the Taylor polynomial.

Comment: In particular, write out the Taylor polynomials $P_0, P_1, P_2$ of $f$ about $0$. Plug those three values in and write out the resulting equations. Solve the system of equations in $f'(0), f''(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Start by $P_{n+1}(x)=P_n(x)+a_{n+1}x^{n+1}$ and you will end up with a super simple set of three equations with three variables to solve.